# fetching from the database (Scheduler + yii)

Tags: php, mysql, yii, dhtmlx-scheduler

I use the scheduler in my yii project. Standard configuration connection to the Events table selects all events from the database.

```
public function actionScheduler_data()
{   
    $currentUser = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $scheduler = new SchedulerConnector(Events::model(), "PHPYii");
    $scheduler->enable_log("text.log");
    $scheduler->configure("-", "event_id", "start_date, end_date, event_name");
    $scheduler->render();
}
```

I need to be more flexible and to give only those events in which the user_id matches id of the current user.. How should I do in this situation? Very need help!

Comment: You have 10 questions, which have 9 answers, and you have not accepted any of them. Are you aware of the acceptance system? Where a question helped you solve a problem, you click the tick mark to the left, so it turns green. This gives the poster a few points, and is a good way of thanking them.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/connector__php__complex_queries.html) documentation on how to use queries to load specific data. As by default the connector loads all data.